# How do I retrieve a Installation ISO file and product key from another hard drive?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, laptop, iso-image, product-key

My laptop, HP Pavilion is not working. I tried to power on with the power cable. It is not working. I want to remove the hard drive from inside the laptop and connect to my old laptop and copy the ISO file and product key to perform the clean installation of Windows 10?

Can kindly advise on how to achieve this?
Can kindly explain on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Once the old disk is connected to the other computer, you may copy
the Windows ISO file, if it is stored somewhere on the disk.
If you haven't kept the ISO file, you will need to get it from
Microsoft at the
[Download Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)
page.

To retrieve the old serial key of Windows from the old disk, use the free
[NirSoft’s ProduKey](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html).

You need to point ProduKey to the disk by using the menu
*File > Select Source > Load the product keys from external Windows directory*
and point it at the Windows directory on the disk.

For more information with screenshots, see the article
[How to Recover Software Product Keys From Any Computer, Even a Broken One](https://www.howtogeek.com/64600/how-to-recover-windows-and-software-keys-from-a-broken-computer/).

Comment: You dont need the serial key, perform as clean install and it will activate with the digital licence,